# importing PARI libraries ( in C++) with Python

Tags: linear-algebra, python, c++

I noticed that Python does not have a good datatype for rational numbers, certainly not for algebraic numbers like $\tfrac{1 + \sqrt{2}}{3}$ or the real root of $x^3 - 5x + 7$.  They have the `fractions` data type and I was able to hack a solution to my particular problem from there using elaborate arrangements of matrices.

It would be really nice to take advance of the `PARI` library which is written in `C`.  Since `GP` is an interface to the PARI, it seems possible to write a Python interface to those libraries.

I can't seem to install [Pari-Python](http://code.google.com/p/pari-python/) so this is a chance to learn to import C libraries directly.

---

At the heart of it, I just want to learn how to import C++ libraries into Python.  Specifically, libraries from the [PARI-GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/) source code.

Comment: Would using Sage work, or are you looking to avoid Sage?

Comment: I would prefer not to use Sage

Answer (score 1):

> I noticed that Python does not have a good datatype for rational numbers, certainly not for algebraic numbers like $\tfrac{1 + \sqrt{2}}{3}$ or the real root of $x^3 - 5x + 7$.  They have the `fractions` data type and I was able to hack a solution to my particular problem from there using elaborate arrangements of matrices.

If the reason you'd prefer not to use Sage is that you don't want to install kitchen sinks, you can do this in Python using [sympy](http://sympy.org/en/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

To import C or C++ code into Python, please see [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/).

However, it might be easier to try to fix the errors you're seeing with installing or importing the `pari-python` library, so maybe post the error(s) you're seeing as a separate question and get them resolved.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to [SWIG](https://github.com/swig/swig) is [Cython](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/external_C_code.html). In [Cython vs SWIG, fight!](http://pyvideo.org/video/1692/cython-vs-swig-fight) you can see a comparison of the syntax for both of them (TL;DW: both need you to write some boating code, each one on a different corner).

I think the main advantage of Cython is the syntax, closer to Python, and that you can easily and progressively convert Python code to C. It is under heavy development, but it is quite stable. It is what most major scientific libraries are using (Numpy, Scipy, scikits...), with a lot of documentation oriented to the scientific stack.

SWIG is a more mature project, also maintained and compatible with other programming languages. I know of some research projects that make heavy use of it; but as far as I can remember, none of the libraries I have ever used in detail.